# How to get twitter user friends/followers by twitteR package?

Tags: r, twitter

I'm having problem with getting **someOne** followers/friends with twitteR package.

It always returns **authenticated account's** friends/followers.

According to documentation, and some online resources;

```
library('twitteR') #version 0.99.19

user <- getUser('someOne')

friends <- user$getFriends() 
# or user$getFriendIDs() etc. related followers methods
# ps: I made successful authentication w/ using ROAuth lib with my own twitter account.
```

Methods seems work well , but it doesn't return someOne's(givenUser) friends/followers.

I hope not , but it seems a bug to me.

If it's not a bug, How can I achieve my aim ?

Comment: what do you have with getUser('@someOne')

Comment: I have an userObject and methods returns correct user objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case you're not on the mailing list - this is/was a bug. It's been fixed in the current dev version (on my github: http://www.github.com/geoffjentry) although there are larger changes w/ that version - specifically conversion to the 1.1 API. It should be finding its way to CRAN soon if you're not brave enough to try the rough version.

Comment: I've already checked dev version and it works now, thanks for the quick update.